# URL for a photo from Google+ album with a specific dimension

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

Does anyone know if it is still possible to get the URL for a photo from a Google+ album with a specific size (800 x 600 pixels, for example), as it was possible to do with Picasa before?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to picasaweb and make it from there, but you must use special url
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos?noredirect=1